# Stripe checkout session is not being created

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I am trying to create a stripe checkout page.
This is my current code.

```
const handleDebitcard = async () => {
    if (orderData !== undefined) {
      try{
        console.log(stripe)
        const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
          payment_method_types: ['card'],
          mode: 'payment',
          line_items: orderData.products.map((product) => {
            const item = productInfo[product.product];
            console.log(item)
            console.log(product)
            return {
              price_data: {
                currency: 'eur',
                product_data: {
                  name: item.name,
                },
                unit_amount: item.price * 100,
              },
              quantity: product.quantity,
            };
          }),
          success_url: 'http://localhost:3001/order/success',
          cancel_url: 'http://localhost:3001/order/cancel',
        });
        console.log("is there a session?")
        console.log(session);
        console.log(session.url);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
  }
```

This is the console log from item

```
{
   category: "T-shirt",
   description: "Short sleeve tshirt 230gram of 100% cotton, 
   Heartless print on front empty back.",
   id: 2,
   image: "image_link",
   name: "Heartless",
   price: 25
}
```

this is the console log from order

```
{
   order:24,
   product:2,
   quantity:1,
   size:"Medium"
}
```

So I get data but the session is just not created all the console.logs from after the stripe session is not getting printed. So for example `console.log("is there a session?")` this is not getting printed.
Any help is greatly appreciated and if you need any more information let me know. Thanks in advance

Comment: either `stripe.checkout.sessions.create` is taking a long time or it's failing silently. are you not seeing any errors?

Comment: I dont see any errors. I also let my code run for a while and still dont see any session so my guess is that it indeed fails somewhere.

Comment: change it to `let promise = stripe.checkout.sessions.create(...); console.log(promise)` and let me know what it logs. don't use `await` this time

Comment: Changed the function to this
const --> let and removed await
now the console.log from the "Is there a session" is printed.
My console.log prints a promise and my session.url prints undefined.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdLfu.png

Comment: a bit misleading to still call that variable `session` since it's just a promise not the session itself. anyway the reason it's now printing the stuff below is cuz you're not awaiting. good so far – are you seeing any requests being made in the network tab?

Comment: What happens if you log your map ? Or even hardcode the `line_items` array to see if that's the source of the issue.

Comment: you could also try logging `session` again after 10 seconds or so and seeing if the status is still "pending"

Comment: There are no requests being made in the network tab

Comment: then something is def broken somewhere. do you have any browser extensions that might be blocking requests from being made? try turning off any extensions...

Comment: you could also check your stripe account for events related to this. maybe need to create a webhook, not a stripe expert. btw don't they say somewhere not to set prices on the client? anyway i'd contact stripe support at this point, let us know what the issue was.

Comment: I removed my browser extensions and still no requests are being made. Also i checked with hardcoding the line items and that is not the issue as it still not works

Comment: I was following a tutorial but ill check their docs to see what is wrong. Thanks for looking into the problem

Comment: Did you check the request history in Stripe [Dashboard](https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs)? If the request isn't shown there, it means no request is made to Stripe. If it shows up, the response should be helpful to debug (if there is an error).

Comment: For everyone who looked into this problem thank you. but my problem is that I am trying to create this checkout session through my frontend and I should be doing this through the backend. But thanks to everyone who was looking into this!